# A way to schedule a method call in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdate, nstimer, background-process

I'd like to call a method

```
-(void) fooWithObject:(MyObject *)obj;
```

On a given time (`NSDate` instance)

without blocking the main thread.

What is the best way to go about this? I've seen `NSTimer`, `performSelector` and `NSOperation` but reading a bit of each just made me more confused.

Important:

- Ability to pass in an object to the method I'm calling
- A way to set time of execution
- Non blocking
- Don't need repeats

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` can be used for this. The delay is relative so you need to compute the difference between your desired date and the current time. Something like this (typed directly into answer on an iPad - E&OE):

```
- (void) fooWithObject:(MyObject *)obj onDate:(NSDate *)onDate
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(fooWithObject:)
               withObject:obj
               afterDelay:MAX(0, [onDate timeIntervalSinceNow])
    ];
}
```

Note that MAX is used in case the passed in date is in the past - the delay will be 0 and the selector will therefore be performed "as soon as possible".

Comment: It's worth noting that this method isn't millisecond-precise. You probably don't want to use it for, like, a pacemaker.

Comment: @Chuck is correct. Under-the-hood `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` uses a timer and is as (im)precise as `NSTimer`. But seriously, I wouldn't use (vanilla) Objective-C for anything safety-critical not just a pacemaker! ;-)

Comment: @SamJarman - No. The selector when performed will be executed on the main thread, if that is an issue there are variants which will execute on a different thread.